# Ruby on Rails NoMethodError in FoodItemsController#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, helper

[image: 1]

This is the error I am getting when I hit submit on my form for uploading an image. Can anyone help me out? I feel like the JSON serialize isnt working. which is causing the error.

```
class FoodItem < ApplicationRecord
mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
serialize :image, JSON # If you use SQLite, add this line
belongs_to :user, optional: true

validates :name, :description, :resturant, :glutenfree, :vegan, presence: true 
validates :description, length: {maximum: 1000, too_long: "%{count} characters is the maximum allowed"}

validates :title, length: {maximum: 140, too_long: "%{count} characters is the maximum allowed"}
```

end

here is my food controller,

```
  class FoodItemsController < ApplicationController
before_action :set_food_item, only: %i[ show edit update destroy ]
before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]
# GET /food_items or /food_items.json
def index
  @food_items = FoodItem.all.order("created_at desc")
end

# GET /food_items/1 or /food_items/1.json
def show
end

# GET /food_items/new FoodItem.new
def new
  @food_item = current_user.food_items.build
end

# GET /food_items/1/edit
def edit
end

# POST /food_items or /food_items.json FoodItem.new(food_item_params)
def create
  @food_item = current_user.food_items.build(food_item_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @food_item.save
      format.html { redirect_to food_items_url(@food_item), notice: "Food item was successfully created." }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @food_item }
    else
      format.html { render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      format.json { render json: @food_item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

# PATCH/PUT /food_items/1 or /food_items/1.json
def update
  respond_to do |format|
    if @food_item.update(food_item_params)
      format.html { redirect_to food_items_url(@food_item), notice: "Food item was successfully updated." }
      format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @food_item }
    else
      format.html { render :edit, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      format.json { render json: @food_item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

# DELETE /food_items/1 or /food_items/1.json
def destroy
  @food_item.destroy

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to food_items_url, notice: "Food item was successfully destroyed." }
    format.json { head :no_content }
  end
end

  # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
  def set_food_item
    @food_item = FoodItem.find(params[:id])
  end

  # Only allow a list of trusted parameters through.
  def food_item_params
    params.require(:food_item).permit(:name, :foodtype, :description, :ingrediants, :resturant, :glutenfree, :vegan, :image)
  end
```

end

I believe the error is being caused by the image not being serialized to json because when I got to /public/images/tmp the images are being uploaded.

Comment: Do you have a DB column for `title` on the FoodItem?

Comment: The model is validating a `title` attribute, but your params doesn´t contain that attribute, include title in strong params or check if your model/schema should validate `title`

Comment: 1. Did you forget to add the migration for the `title` column?
2. Did you forget to run the migrations `rails db:migrate`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. run `rails db:migrate` if title field not found foodItem_table
2. add title into food_item_params

```
 def food_item_params
    params.require(:food_item).permit(:name, :foodtype, :description, :ingrediants, :resturant, :glutenfree, :vegan, :image, :title)
  end
```

3: run `rails s`